# Evaluating the Scalar triple product

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

How can I evaluate the following:
(2**w**×**u**)•(3**v**), by knowing only that **u**•(**v**×**w**)=-3

Answer (score 2):

Use

- the *laws of distribution* for scalar product across both vector multiplications,
- the *anticommutivity* of the cross product
- the *commutivity* of the dot product
- the *circular shift* property of the vector tripple product.